# 追 as in 追剧 (chasing a TV series)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

I am native speaker but I haven't yet figured out the exact meaning of 追 as in 追剧 - 'chasing a TV series'. Does it mean 'stay on top', 'catch up' or simply 'actively watch'? In other words,

- Does it exclusively refer to watching the latest episode on air, or at least keep oneself up to the season?
- Does it count as 追 if I am watching the past season on DVD in order to catch up and watch the current season?
- Does it count as 追 if I am watching a series that has already finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes. This is exactly what `追剧` mean.
- No.
- No.

We may call actions in last two question as `煲剧` or `补番` .

EDIT:

There is a funny name `坑` (means 'hole') for the series that have many seasons to watch. When we start watching it, we call it `开坑` (start a hole), and the process we watch from the S01E01 to the latest episode, we call it `填坑` (filling the hole).
That a funny saying we are using.

Answer (score 1):

**百度百科**

> 背景
>
> 追剧行为的产生是随着周播剧的产生而诞生的。周播剧是每周拍一集更新一集，如美剧《新生活大爆炸》、韩剧《来自星星的你》和网络剧《报告老板》，不能一次性看完就需要每周固定时间来看新更新的剧目。

So it seems to refer to keeping up with a tv show in the sense of watching it every week when it's broadcasted.